# get_posts() from parent category only using a shortcode

Tags: categories, shortcode, get-posts

I am trying to get_posts() from a category that has a subcategory within. To show an example please look at the image just below.

[image: Categories]

So, as you can see. The parent and the children have posts inside. I want to preview the content within the children only once not twice. The following image shows what I mean. You can see that some items are retrieved twice.

[image: Duplicates]

I have created a shortcode, but I don't know how to make the first part of it get only the posts in the parent category (from desserts first), then show the posts in the subcategories (Baked cookie dough and Pancakes) if exist.

```php
add_shortcode('TEDS_MENU', 'fetch_teds_menu_items');
function fetch_teds_menu_items($atts)
{
  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'category_name' => ''
  ), $atts);

  $category = get_term_by('name', $atts['category_name'], 'category');

  if (!$category) {
    return '';
  }

  $args = array(
    'category__in' => [$category->term_id],
    'post_type' => 'menu',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  );

  $subcategories = get_categories(
    array(
      'parent' => $category->term_id
    )
  );

  $output = '<section id="' . $category->slug . '">';
  $menu_items = get_posts($args);
  foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
    setup_postdata($menu_item);
    $output .= '<div class="teds-menu-item-wrapper">';
    $output .= '<h3 class="teds-menu-item__title">' . $menu_item->post_title . '</h3>';
    $output .= '<div class="teds-menu-item">';
    $output .= '<div class="teds-menu-item-description">';
    $output .= '<p class="teds-menu-item-description__text">' . $menu_item->post_content . '</p>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<ul class="teds-menu-prices-list">';
    if (get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, 'regular_size_price')[0] || get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, 'large_size_price')[0]) {
      $output .= '<li class="menu-prices-list--item">R ' . get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, 'regular_size_price')[0]  . ' EGP</li>';
      $output .= '<li class="menu-prices-list--item">L ' . get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, 'large_size_price')[0] . ' EGP</li>';
    }
    if (get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, 'price')[0]) {
      $output .= '<li class="teds-menu-prices-list--item">' . get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, 'price')[0] . ' EGP</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
  }
  if ($subcategories) {
    $output .= '<section class="teds-menu-subcategory">';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
      $output .= '<div class="teds-menu-subcategory__content">';
      $output .= '<h2 class="teds-subcategory-title">' . $subcategory->name . '</h2>';
      $subcategory_items = get_posts(array(
        'category' => $subcategory->cat_ID,
        'post_type' => 'menu',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
      ));
      foreach ($subcategory_items as $subcategory_item) {
        $output .= '<div class="teds-subcategory-item">';
        $output .= '<div class="teds-subcategory-item__content">';
        $output .= '<h3 class="teds-subcategory-item__title">' . $subcategory_item->post_title . '</h3>';
        if ($subcategory_item->post_content) {
          $output .= '<p class="class="menu-prices-list--item teds-subcategory-item__desc">' . $subcategory_item->post_content . '</p>';
        }
        $output .= '</div>';
        if (get_post_meta($subcategory_item->ID, 'price')[0]) {
          $output .= '<ul class="teds-menu-prices-list">';
          $output .= '<li class="teds-menu-prices-list--item">' . get_post_meta($subcategory_item->ID, 'price')[0] . ' EGP</li>';
          $output .= '</ul>';
        }
        $output .= '</div>';
      }
      $output .= '</div>';
      wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $output .= '</section>';
  }
  $output .= "</section>";
  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $output;
}
```

> **UPDATE:** Following [@Sally CJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj)'s answer solves the issue of some
>   posts being displayed twice. But in some other categories, posts have
>   disappeared. For example, the following categories include posts but they are not displayed any more:

[image: Missing posts]

[image: Missing posts 2]

[image: Missing preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include posts in child categories, use the `category__in` parameter:

```php
$args = array(
  'category__in' => [ get_cat_ID( $category_name ) ], // use category__in
  //'category_name' => $category_name,                // and not this.
  'post_type' => 'menu',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

And although the above would give you what you wanted, the following might help you..

```php
function fetch_teds_menu_items($atts)
{
  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'category_name' => ''
  ), $atts);

  if ( ! $category = get_term_by( 'name', $atts['category_name'], 'category' ) ) {
    return '';
  }

  $args = array(
    'category__in' => [ $category->term_id ],
    'post_type' => 'menu',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  );

  $meta_data = get_term_meta($category->term_id, 'category_featured_image', TRUE);
  // $category_image = wp_get_attachment_url($meta_data);

  $subcategories = get_categories(
    array(
      'parent' => $category->term_id
    )
  );

  $output = '<section id="' . $category->slug . '">';
  ...
  return $output;
}
```

I.e. I use `get_term_by()` to get the full category object by its name (not slug, but can be slug).

PS: The `category` parameter also include child categories — `'category' => $subcategory->cat_ID,`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I want to ask about something because there is something weird happened. Some categories that include posts are now not displayed for some reason which I don't know why. I updated the question so you can understand me better.

Comment: Can I see your current code? And if possible, can you export *published* posts in the "Gourmet Burgers" & "Additions" categories? (Replace sensitive data like domain names)

Comment: I replaced the old code now. And you can find the export in gist: https://gist.github.com/Tes3awy/0f653de53b05eb8e5a774d850806a4d6

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not getting the issue.. are you sure you used the correct category name (I know you might did based on the screenshot in the question, but just in case)? `[TEDS_MENU category_name="Gourmet Burgers"]` ?

Comment: It's weird that it worked after you said you aren't getting the issue :D. Can't thank you enough. Thank you :). You literally saved the day <3

Comment: Maybe caching issue or you forgot or made a mistake in certain parts of the code.. but whatever it was, I hope it won't happen again. :)